CHAID package not installing on r version 4.3 but works for others
I am trying to install the CHAID package using install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org") which was given to me by my professor.  I was on r version 4.3.3 but also tried it on 4.3.1. The error I am getting is

install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Chase/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘CHAID’ is not available for this version of R
A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository http://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
cannot open URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'

The reason I am confused is that others in the class are also working in versions 4.3.1/4.3.2/4.3.3 and it is working for them.  I tried searching around but haven't seen anybody else who has had this problem and been able to fix it, and I am simply not experienced enough with r to solve it myself.
I tried using r 4.3.1 as that was the version that worked for someone else, but I encountered the exact same problem.  I also tried installing partykit and that did not help either.  I haven't tried it yet but I am tempted to use an even older version of r, but I'm afraid it will mess up other packages.
